# Git API to attach the file/image from my local computer to Open pull request

Tags: git, api, github

I would need an API to attach the file/image to one of my open pull requests

I had the API for open pull request is

```
https://<>/api/v3/repos/<>/<>/pulls/1123
```

Answer (score 2):

GitHub doesn't offer an API to upload a file for use in an issue or pull request comment.  This ability is only possible in the web interface.

However, you can specify a normal Markdown image link to an external location, such as a server you host or a cloud storage bucket, and such a link should work.